# How can I index duplicate items in an array?

Tags: ruby

Starting with the following array (of hashes):

```
[
  {:name=>"site a", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/"}, 
  {:name=>"site b", :url=>"http://example.org/site/2/"}, 
  {:name=>"site c", :url=>"http://example.org/site/3/"}, 
  {:name=>"site d", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/"}, 
  {:name=>"site e", :url=>"http://example.org/site/2/"}, 
  {:name=>"site f", :url=>"http://example.org/site/6/"},
  {:name=>"site g", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/"}
]
```

How can I add an index of the duplicate urls like so:

```
[
  {:name=>"site a", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/", :index => 1}, 
  {:name=>"site b", :url=>"http://example.org/site/2/", :index => 1}, 
  {:name=>"site c", :url=>"http://example.org/site/3/", :index => 1}, 
  {:name=>"site d", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/", :index => 2}, 
  {:name=>"site e", :url=>"http://example.org/site/2/", :index => 2}, 
  {:name=>"site f", :url=>"http://example.org/site/6/", :index => 1},
  {:name=>"site g", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/", :index => 3}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a hash for keeping track of the indices.
Scanning the previous entries again and again seems inefficient

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
array.each { | hash | 
  hash[:index] = counts[hash[:url]] = counts[hash[:url]] + 1
}
```

or a bit cleaner

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { | hash, counts | 
  hash[:index] = counts[hash[:url]] = counts[hash[:url]] + 1
}
```

Comment: I think it is inefficient too, but depends on Array size.

Comment: you can use liek @mu `each_with_object` here: `array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){ |counts, hash| hash[:index] = counts[hash[:url]] = counts[hash[:url]] + 1}`

Comment: both @fl00r and this answer worked great; just found this one easier to grok.

Comment: @floor: Thanks, updated. This is because I'm using 1.8.6 here which does not have `each_with_object`.

Answer (score 3):

```
array = [
  {:name=>"site a", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/"}, 
  {:name=>"site b", :url=>"http://example.org/site/2/"}, 
  {:name=>"site c", :url=>"http://example.org/site/3/"}, 
  {:name=>"site d", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/"}, 
  {:name=>"site e", :url=>"http://example.org/site/2/"}, 
  {:name=>"site f", :url=>"http://example.org/site/6/"},
  {:name=>"site g", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/"}
]

array.inject([]) { |ar, it| 
    count_so_far = ar.count{|i| i[:url] == it[:url]}
    it[:index] = count_so_far+1
    ar << it
}
#=>
[
  {:name=>"site a", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/", :index=>1}, 
  {:name=>"site b", :url=>"http://example.org/site/2/", :index=>1}, 
  {:name=>"site c", :url=>"http://example.org/site/3/", :index=>1}, 
  {:name=>"site d", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/", :index=>2}, 
  {:name=>"site e", :url=>"http://example.org/site/2/", :index=>2}, 
  {:name=>"site f", :url=>"http://example.org/site/6/", :index=>1}, 
  {:name=>"site g", :url=>"http://example.org/site/1/", :index=>3}
]
```

Comment: Excellent, now I'm just trying to get my head around how that works... :)

Comment: I reformatted the `inject` call to hopefully make it clearer. `inject` loops over the receiving array, and in every call to the inject block, `ar` will contain the URLs (and their running counts) it's seen "so far" - because they're being added at the end of the block. So at the start, you count how many of the "current" URL you've seen so far, and add that. It's a little clunky to explain because it's really a recursive operation in disguise. (With thanks to @fl00r for graciously letting me try and make his code comprehensible.)

Comment: I would replace `count_so_far = ar.count{|i| i[:url] == it[:url]}` with `count_so_far = ar[ar.rindex{|i| i[:url] == it[:url]}][:index]`If you have a lot of elements will have better performance.

Comment: @Sii why? When in G the rindex will return 3, as I would expect it to.

Comment: @Serabe: Actually, no, you're right, I missed that you're retrieving the previous running count. It just took me a while to handle the case where `rindex` returns `nil`

Comment: @Sii look at the docs [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000238)

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted it to be efficient, I'd write:

```
items_with_index = items.inject([[], {}]) do |(output, counts), h|
  new_count = (counts[h[:url]] || 0) + 1
  [output << h.merge(:index => new_count), counts.update(h[:url] => new_count)]
end[0]
```